# Debugging Android-AIR app using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, debugging, air, intellij-idea

I'm learning Flex mobile application development, and I started with Android (I tinkered with Android, but figured it might be easier to use AIR, since I already know Flex.

Anyway, I set up a simple a project in IntelliJ IDEA, following this:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/mobile-air-android/

I can't figure out how to debug though. The AIR runtime on my Android phone keeps complaining about unable to listen to port 7936. The error message suggests that I should change the port. But I can't find that option in IDEA.

The article above suggests I turn off the firewall or unblock the port. I tried both. I tried updating the AIR runtime from the Android Market too.

All fruitless. I can run my app and the simple text+button+list works fine. But I just can't get it to debug. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct place to ask IntelliJ IDEA related questions is our forum and issue tracker:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net

As for this question - next update release of IntelliJ IDEA will contain the field for selecting USB debug port.